# How to create scripts which will across windows/linux environments

Tags: mysql, shell, batch-file

We have a simple script to connect to the database (`mysql -u root -p -h localhost`). I don't want to create 2 scripts (`.bat, .sh`), how do I just create a single script to address this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to give MSYS a try: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS

Comment: To elaborate on Dan answer.  If you only want to use one script, then you will need to use the same command line parser on both computers.  MSYS will allow you to run bash on Windows.  See this post for a big list of different tools for running bash on Windows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913912/bash-shell-for-windows

Answer (score 1):

you can use perl scripts. Perl is powerful scripting medium which is platform independent. 
use can insert batch command in a variable in perl.
for eg

```
#!C:\Perl64\bin\perl
my $cmd = 'mysql - u root -p -h localhost';
system $cmd;
```

This should work fine.